# Sending a txt file to a server via TCP on Python Socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to send a `.txt` file from client-side to a server via TCP. The server should be able to count the words and characters of the text file.

But I am getting an error when sending the text file to the server:

```
 "CLIENT_SOCKET.sendto(str(FILENAME).encode(4096)), (SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT)
 TypeError: encode() argument 'encoding' must be str, not int"
```

I don't really understand how the error is occurring.

```
import socket // This is the client 

SERVER_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_PORT = 54321

CLIENT_SOCKET = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

CLIENT_SOCKET.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

FILENAME = input(str("What file would you like to upload?"))
f = open(FILENAME, "r")
FILE_DATA = f.read(4096)
f.close()

print(FILENAME)
CLIENT_SOCKET.sendto(str(FILENAME).encode(4096)), (SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT)

RECEIVED_WORDS, SERVER_HOST = CLIENT_SOCKET.recvfrom(4096)
RECEIVED_CHAR, SERVER_HOST = CLIENT_SOCKET.recvfrom(4096)

print(RECEIVED_WORDS.decode())
print(RECEIVED_CHAR.decode())


CLIENT_SOCKET.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `CLIENT_SOCKET.sendto(str(FILENAME).encode(4096)), (SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT)` you are passing the argument `4096` (an integer) to a method `encode` that expects a string.

Based on the fact that you are sending text I would suggest that you use utf-8 encoding, an example of how to do this follows:

`CLIENT_SOCKET.sendto(str(FILENAME).encode('utf-8')), (SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT)`

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) for details on how to use python string encoding and the various possible values that can be passed to `encode`